# If I terminate a python subprocess, does it clear the associated variable memory?

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, subprocess

I have the following code:

```
import subprocess
import os
import gc

p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'def_train_models.py'])
while(True):
    poll = p.poll()
    if not (poll == None):
        p.terminate()
        p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'def_train_models.py'])
        gc.collect()
```

My def_train_models.py has a memory leak problem, whereby if I continuously run it long enough, it fills up my memory. So what I did was put it into a subprocess. My question is, if I terminate the subprocess as shown in the code, will the associated memory within the subprocess be terminated as well?
I know its bad practice to leave an unresolved memory problem, but this particular case is still valuable to me as a final catch all.

Comment: in most cases yes or why not working with multiprocessing module like the following https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/amp/

Comment: Your question’s title asks whether it *clears* the memory whereas the body asks whether it will be “terminated” which apparently is supposed to mean “freed”, which is not the same as “cleared”.